# Android AppBar listview

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve such a behavior.

This is the initial View:

[image: Initial View]

After clicking the "+" icon, which is a part of an app bar, a following list with filter should appear:

[image: After + clicking]

The underlying activity should still be "active" and should process notifications from a bound service.

How should I proceed? How can I create such a "subview"?

Comment: Did you try PopupMenu? http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: try with option menu or contextual menu

Comment: You can create dialog with transparent background...